# Dev/Test Azure Application Gateway with valid TLS cert and Azure assigned DNS name

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I'm looking for options to deploy an application behind Azure Application Gateway with a valid SSL/TLS certificate and a DNS name that Azure provides/manages for testing purposes. In other words, "I do X" and I get an appgw with a DNS entry "somethingsomething.cloudapps.azure.com" which has a valid SSL certificate.

Does Azure provide such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Application Gateway does not front a SSL certificate on a Microsoft hosted domain like services like App Service and APIM.

If I were you, I'd purchase an [App Service Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal) and then just configure the Azure DNS Zone with the DNS A-record you require to the Application Gateway Public IP.

Comment: I was under the impression that App Service is different from App Gateway. How these two would interplay?

Comment: App Service is a different service, yes. It's responsible for hosting web applications. However an App Service Certificate can be leveraged without using App Service, this gives you a domain & SSL that you require. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#buy-and-import-app-service-certificate